# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am trying to change from React.createClass to React.Component, but I am getting below error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

I googled for the error but an not able to figure it out

```js
class Accordion extends React.Component {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this`.

`this.onSelect -> this.onSelect.bind(this)`

`this.enhanceSection -> this.enhanceSection.bind(this)`

Comment: Hey that one got fixed but I am getting child undefined error here id = child.props.id;

Comment: can you tell the reason it will help in understanding

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your `onSelect` to the class in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected: props.selected // use props, not this.props
    };
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
}
```

The `extends` syntax no longer has autobinding like `createClass` did.

- http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Hey that one got fixed but I am getting child undefined error here id = child.props.id;

Comment: @im  can you tell the reason it will help in understanding

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this.onSelect`
 If you forget to bind this.onSelect and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

Try this:

```js
class SectionAccordion extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onSelect  = this.onSelect.bind(this);
      }

      onSelect() {

        this.props._onSelect(this.props.id);
      }

      render() {

            console.log("accordion / the Accordion Section component");
            var className = 'accordion-section' + (this.props._selected ? ' selected' : '');

            return (
                <div className={className}>
                    <h3 onClick={this.onSelect}>
                        {this.props.title}
                    </h3>

                    <div className="up-arrow"></div>



                    <div onClick={this.onSelect} className="body">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );

      }

    }
```

**Update:**

You can bind the context using `arrow function` as well ; like this:

```
onSelect = () => {
   // code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hey that one got fixed but I am getting child undefined error here id = child.props.id;

Comment: can you tell the reason it will help in understanding

Comment: In `JavaScript`, `class` methods are not bound by default. If you forget to `bind this.onSelect ` and pass it to `onClick`, this will be `undefined` when the `function` is actually called.

This is not React-specific behavior, it is a part of how functions work in `JavaScript`. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as `onClick={this. onSelect}`, you should `bind` that method..